# How do I stop spaces from displaying as carriage returns when read in from a file?

Tags: c++, file, input, stl

```
void displayFile()
{
    char userInput[20];//Used to store the typed input commands from the user.
    ifstream ip("D:\\H Drive ITT\\Level 8 Degree\\Software Dev (Andrew)\\MiniProject\\about.txt");//Input from file

    string line ;//Store each line in the string
    int exit = 0;//Used to hold the value which indicates whether or not the function should end determined by the user.

    if (ip)//ip is true if the file exists.
    {}
    else
    {
        cout << "-Error_File_Not_Found" << endl;
    }


    while (!ip.eof())//Scan till end of file
    {
        ip >> line;
        cout << line << endl;

    }
    cout << "Type exit to return" << endl << endl << ">>>" ;
    do {
        cin >> userInput;
        if (strcmp(userInput, "exit") == 0 || strcmp(userInput, "EXIT") == 0 || strcmp(userInput, "eXIT") == 0 || strcmp(userInput, "Exit") == 0)
        {
            exit = 1;
        }
        else
        {
            exit = 0;
        }

    } while (exit !=1);
    ip.close();


}

//The
//output
//displays
//like 
//this.
```

When the code runs it takes in the paragraph and displays each word on a line of its own. I have seen solutions that involve classes but I need a different solution as I have not done classes yet.

Comment: You can read file line by line using getline. 
while (std::getline(ip, line))

Comment: Pointing out the bright-blazingly obvious in the slim case that it matters at all - `endl` is equivalent to a newline character. (In case OP wonders, I doubt that's his problem, but JIK...!)

Comment: Also, unrelated efficiency note - if that really is an empty block below `if (ip)` in your code, you can just drop it and say `if (!ip)` to say "If it doesn't exist."

Comment: `>>` reads in the next word, with word defined as "separated by whitespace"; and "whitespace" includes a lot more than newlines.  In other words, you are not currently reading in line, by line; but word by word.  Once you figure out how to read in line by line, your output will be trivial to get right.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two problems here.

1. The `>>` operator does not read lines, it stops on whitespace. Use `std::getline` as Ramana suggested in the comments.
2. You are using `eof()` incorrectly. It returns true *after* you have already read past the end of the file, not *before* you would read past the end. So your loop will iterate one time too many. The best method is to use the return value of `std::getline` as the loop condition.